# How to reverse String Array by using loop in java

Tags: java, arrays, string

I want to write program to reverse String Array by using for loop in Java, don't suggest any method stringBuffer or StringBuilder, not even to string instead of String Array.

Below is my code, here I am getting an error, ie Cannot invoke charAt(int) on the array type String[].

```
package demo;

public class ReverseString1 {
    String[] x={"Welcome"};
    String y;
    int i,j;

    void reverse1(){
        for(int i = x.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            y = y + x.charAt(i);
            System.out.print(y);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ReverseString1 obj = new ReverseString1();
        obj.reverse1();
    }
}
```

Comment: please edit your question to include this code, formatted as `code`

Comment: @O.O.Balance done ,now please check

Comment: Why are you insisting on using an array of Strings? Would you like for every String in the array to be reversed? (you could amend your code to include more than one element in the array)

Comment: just confirming what you want to do. Do you want to reverse all strings in a string array ? [does your string array ever even have more than one string ?] or do you want to reverse the order of strings in your string array ?

Comment: @O.O.Balance this is only the requirement ie using array of String and my i know array of String can include more string ,but currently i have to do with single string on array.

Comment: @kshishoo as i mentioned i wanted to reverse the single string on array with loop statement .

Comment: Let's not discourage beginners from asking questions.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `x` is an array. Arrays don't have a `charAt()` method, hence the error.

Maybe you meant to write:

```
void reverse1(){
    for(int i = x[0].length()-1; i >= 0; i--){
        y=y + x[0].charAt(i);
        System.out.print(y);
    }
}
```

Note that I have changed the `for` loop statement as well so it iterates over the String at index 0, not the array.

Or maybe you want a `char[]` instead of a `String[]`?
Then your code could look something like this:

```
char[] x = new char[] {'W', 'e', 'l', 'c', 'o', 'm', 'e'};

void reverse1(){
    for(int i = x.length-1; i >= 0; i--){
        y=y + x[i];
        System.out.print(y);
    }
}
```

Also, you probably want to print `y` outside of the loop.

Comment: ,i got ur point that array doesnt have charAt function ,but with ur piece of code ,it will return null value for last index,still it doesnt serve my problem.

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand what you are trying to say. Maybe you could specify your problem more clearly (have you read the comments under your question?).

Answer (score 0):

int i,j;

void reverse1(){

```
for(int i = x.length-1; i >= 0; i--){
   y = "";
   for(int j = x[i].length-1; j >= 0; j--){
       y=y + x[i].charAt(j);
   }
   System.out.print(y);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can reverse a `String`

```
String reverse(String input) {
    //input is a String
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length() / 2; i++) {
        char aux = input.charAt(i);
        input.setCharAt(i, input.charAt(input.length - 1 - i));
        input.setCharAt(input.length - 1 - i, aux);
    }
}
```

Now, let's reverse all items of a `String` array:

```
String[] reverse(String[] input) {
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        input[i] = reverse(input[i]);
    }
}
```

Note that it is not feasible to mix printing the results with calculations. I have given you the way you can do the calculations, as I have observed that you already know how to print the results. The effective problem you had was that `x` is an array of `String` and you will need to iterate it to get its `String` items. In the case of your code it will result in

```
void reverse1(){

    for(int j = 0; j < x.length; j++) {
        for(int i = x[j].length()-1; i >= 0; i--){
            y=y + x[j].charAt(i);
            System.out.print(y);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank ,i have already tried this piece of code but problem is that it also print null value at the beginning,now here is fight

Comment: output seems like : nullemoclew

Comment: @snig y was not initialized. Define it by initializing it via y = ''; That should solve your problem, but when you manage to fix your code, you should switch to my solution described before the fix for your solution, as it is much more elegant.